# VBA HTML Login and Password via Intranet InternetExplorerMedium

Tags: html, vba

here is a piece of the source code I cannot seem to break in order to input my username and password:

```
<div style="width: 30%;">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 10%">Username:</td>
            <td class="required"><input type="text" name="j_username"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td class="required"><input type="password" name="j_password"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td class="input"><input type="submit" value="Log in"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Here is my Code. I am simply looking to add the username, passsword and then click submit to log in to my site. I have tried many different approaches, but I cannot seem to get the right object tree.

```
 Sub ImportIntra()

 'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
 Dim ie As InternetExplorer

 'to refer to the HTML document returned
 Dim html As HTMLDocument

 'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
 Set ie = New InternetExplorerMedium

 ie.Visible = True
 ie.Navigate "https://www.placeholder.com"

 'Wait until IE is done loading page
 Do While ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
 Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to StackOverflow ..."
 DoEvents
 Loop

 'show text of HTML document returned
 Set html = ie.Document


 Dim doc As New HTMLDocument, els, el

 doc.body.innerHTML = html.DocumentElement.innerHTML

 Set Var = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(0).Value = "123"
 Set Var = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(1).Value = "123"
 Set Var = doc.getElementsByTagName("input")(2).Value = "123"

 'close down IE and reset status bar
 Set ie = Nothing

 Application.StatusBar = ""

 End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok solved it. The code required this instead:

```
 Set doc = ie.Document
 Set LoginForm = doc.forms(0)
 Set PasswordInputBox = LoginForm.elements("j_username")
 PasswordInputBox.Value = "123"
```

Comment: Also consider using getElementsbyClassName.